# getting url with php after modifying

Tags: php, url, request-uri

I have the following link with the following url.

```
<a href="superoffice/config/sov3_view.php?logtrace=0">link</a>
```

when i get to the link page the url is of course

```
../sove3_view.php?logtrace=0
```

but when i change 0 to 1 like following

```
../sove3_view.php?logtrace=1
```

and try to get using

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

i still get the following

```
../sove3_view.php?logtrace=0
```

while i want to get

```
../sove3_view.php?logtrace=1
```

how can i get the url after modifying query string value?

Comment: "when i get to the link page the url is of course" - there's nothing "of course" about that, that is very weird. In short, I haven't a clue what you're asking, and within which context, about which variables.

Comment: You're modifying *without* reloading? If that is the case you'll never get the new string because no new request was made.

Comment: Actually the `?logtrace=0` is never part of the uri, it is the query part of the url. From your wording it is unclear where you see that string. What I can imagine is that you have some rewriting rule present in your http server that internally rewrites to the url with the trailing query part with the value 0 which does not consider the actually given query arg at all.